# How to do performance test for a golang sdk method?

Tags: go, testing, sdk, performance-testing, benchmarking

I am wondering how to do performance test for a golang sdk method? I am optimizing a sdk method. This method on this SDK will make http requests to other services when called.

I have two implementations for the method(one is using 3 http requests and the other is using only 1 http request) and I want to do a performance testing on responding time.

I have used **go test -benchmark**, but I searched online and it says it shall not be used to do benchmark for code with external services.

Wondering what shall be the **correct tools** and **method** to do a benchmark not just on golang performance, but also on external services performance.

Comment: You seem to be trying to do load testing.

Comment: @BurakSerdar But I mainly want to test about response time haha

Comment: Do you want to know if your Go code is faster, or if this one big request to the service is quicker than the three smaller ones? The answer will likely depend on the network latency between you and the server, and the load on the server. All you can do is try, `go test -bench` will work for this, but you must consider that sometimes the answer might be that you have improved performance, and sometimes the same code might degrade performance. You need to consider who you are improving performance for and replicate their environment.